# Add a new property to an image in C#

Tags: c#, image, properties

Is there a way to add a new property to an existing image?

I would like to set my own **ID property** for later references.

Comment: have you tried extending Image and simply adding a new property?

Comment: You must clarify what you mean as image. `System.Drawing.Image`, ...

Comment: Do you mean you want the property stored in the file which has the image, i.e. in its metadata?

Comment: There are lots and lots of possibilities.  Only trumped by the number of ways you can lose that ID again when the image file is transferred or converted.  You have to put constraints on what kind of data loss you consider acceptable to get an answer.

Comment: Hi, Actually im just looking for the best way to add a unique signature/id to my image object. everytime using this image i would like to get that unique id and search the db for its history.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.tag.aspx) property to store any object type.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, then this is the entire point of object oriented programming.

```
Class ExtendedImage : Image {
  public IDtype ID { get; private set; }

  public ExtendedImage(IDtype ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes, that is what i'm after. Will I be able to store this id in the image object next time usage? will it be as tag?

Comment: Assuming OP's talking about `System.Drawing.Image`, this wouldn't work. `Image` is an abstract class with an `internal` constructor accessor. It may be possible to extend another class that implements it but I suspect they're similar to the `Bitmap` class in that they're `sealed` classes thus preventing any inheritance.